# Table View in View Controller using Core Data

Tags: core-data, tableview

I am using core data and am trying to add table view cells to a table view in a view controller. When I implement it in a table view controller the app runs. When I run it when the table view is part of another view controller, the app does not run. It shows an error in the code: property tableview not found on object of type DeviceViewController. DeviceViewController.h has a table view data source and delegate. My code is:

```
 #import "DeviceViewController.h"
#import "DeviceDetailViewController.h"

 @interface DeviceViewController ()
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *devices;
@end

@implementation DeviceViewController

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
}
return context;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
// Custom initialization
}
return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}     

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

 // Fetch the devices from persistent data store
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Device"];
self.devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil]             mutableCopy];

[self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return self.devices.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier           forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
NSManagedObject *device = [self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", [device valueForKey:@"name"]]];

return cell;
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
return YES;
}


  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:        (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
// Delete object from database
[context deleteObject:[self.devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

NSError *error = nil;
   if (![context save:&error]) {
NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
return;
}

// Remove device from table view
[self.devices removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self. otableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it, in this case, it has nothing to do with CoreData.

You should add the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols to your VC.
After that you should create a UITableView (you can do it in interface builder) and connect the datasource and delegate to your view controller.

You can also add a property for the `UITableView` in your VC.

When you use `UITableViewController`, all this is done from Xcode, but if you use `UITableView` inside a regular `UIViewController` you should take care of this stuff.

Good Luck!

EDIT:

Add this as a propert

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *deviceTableView;
```

Change the `viewDidLoad` method to this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _deviceTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    _deviceTableView.delegate = self;
    _deviceTableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:_deviceTableView];
    [_deviceTableView reloadData];
}
```

Delete what you have written in `viewDidAppear` and replace `self.tableView` with `_deviceTableView` everywhere in this file.

Comment: I did this, but it is crashing when it loads. Showing a SIGBART error

Comment: what is the exception message that you get?

Comment: I changed some things and added this to my viewdidappear function:
        DeviceViewController *deviceViewController =         [[DeviceViewController alloc]init];
        deviceViewController.tableView = self.tableView;
        self.tableView.dataSource = deviceViewController;
        self.tableView.delegate = deviceViewController;


Now, it is showing a breakpoint on  [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: The stuff you have written in `viewDidAppear` are wrong. Delete them. See my edited post. Also read a few tutorials on ViewControllers and UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem that could be causing the crashes is if your NSManagedObjectContext is nil when you are trying to execute the fetch request. I would add an `if([self managedObjectContext])` 
before using it in any of your view hierarchy methods.

Also, you should be careful when using views instantiated from storyboards. Nikola's answer said to add the code configuring the view controller in viewDidLoad, and that is ok as long as you did not drag a UITableView onto your UIViewController instance in interface builder. If you already have created and linked a tableview in interface builder, you will be needlessly replacing it with a new one, so before the 
    _deviceTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
line, you should add an `if(!_deviceTableView)`
statement because it will prevent you from adding a second table view to your view. The issue is that if you have already added a tableview in IB, it will be retained by your view even after you change your tableview property, so it is possible to have two tables show up.

Alternatively, you could use "lazy instantiation" in your getter method for the table view property to make sure it is initialized when you access it.

Lastly, in order to help give us a better idea of why your app is crashing it would be helpful to get the exception log from the console in Xcode.

Comment: I think the problem is when the NSManagedObjectContext is executing the fetch request, could you please tell me what code to write.

Comment: I know there is something wrong with the viewdidappear function, I just dont know what and how to change it, could you please help me

Comment: A couple more things that I noticed in the viewDidAppear function, none of them can be directly related to the crash, but they are problems all the same that you probably want to fix. First, in your managedObjectContext getter, you call `if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)])` when you probably want `respondsToSelector:` instead, as performSelector will still make your app crash if it doesn't exist. The second thing is that when a fetch request is used for a tableview you must use a sort descriptor so the objects come back in the same order every time you execute it.

Comment: Although until we can see a crash log, unfortunately I do not think that we will be able to tell where the crash originates for certain. However, my gut tells me that you don't have a property `tableview` on your custom view controller. That is why it says `property tableview not found`. If your class is a subclass of UITableViewController, then the property is `@property(nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tableView` (with a capital 'V')

Comment: I added the custom table view controller. Even then this problem is occurring. I know there is a problem with the view did appear method as when i deleted it, everything worked fine except for the save method I have on another VC.